# operators within the dollar sign

Tags: math-operators

I am using operators : `+`,`-`. For example, `$6-1$`. The operator `-` becomes rather large between `$ $`.

Normally, would you leave the operator negative between the `$$`? If not, how do you make it to the normal size ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  Are you referring to the size of the operator, or to the spacing on either side?  The size and spacing that `$6-1$` produces _is_ considered the correct math spacing. The minus should definitely be within the dollar signs as long as it is minus operation.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I was wrong. I was putting the minus sign outside.

Answer (score 8):

Since you're referring to `-` in the mathematical context, use it as such in (La)TeX. So, use `$-i$` instead of `-$i$`. Use `$k+p$` instead of `$k$+$p$`. Here are some examples of the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
If I use -$i$, the spacing around the symbol and operator is not correct. 
Compare this to $-i$. 
Also, when using these operators in a binary sense, it should be used as $k+p$, and not $k$+$p$.

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    Wrong & Correct \\ \hline
    -$i$ & $-i$ \\
    $k$+$p$ & $k+p$
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I was putting the minus sign outside which is wrong. I would correct it now.